# How to pass Variable in Find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-3.7

I want to pass variables to driver.find_elemet_by_xpath

when I use it like this it's ok

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_String')
```

but when I use it like this it doesn't run successfully

```
Item = 'Xpath_string'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(Item)
```

Comment: You might just have a typo in the variable... `'xpath_String'` not `'Xpath_string'`

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following element in DOM:

```
<div id="carbon-block"></div>
```

To get that element by `xpath` you would write your xpath string like this: `.//div[@id='carbon-block']`

Now, assume the `id` of the element is being changed by whatever logic in your application and is different based on that logic:

```
id1 = 'carbon-block-1'
id2 = 'carbon-block-2'
xpath = f'.//div[@id=\'{id1}\']'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

NOTE:
The `id` was used just for the sake of the example.

Comment: Are those changes completely random? if those are limited you can use `or` condition to specify the multiple ids.  `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='option1'] | //*[@id='option2']").click()`

Comment: @MikeCode as I mentioned, the `id` was just for the sake of the example. However, and `or` operator can be used and it can be used inside the same xpath element like this: `.//*[@id='option1' or @id='option2']` since you're not specifying the `tag` type.